# Timeout error while using KSOAP2 in android

Tags: android, timeout, android-ksoap2, timeoutexception, soapfault

I have created a client server application in android and asp.net. I have done the web service access using ksoap2. The application works fine. But sometimes when I try to connect the server using the Ksoap2, then an error arises out. The error log is shown below. This error happens only when the android client tries to communicate the server. Is there any way to eliminate this error? After this error occurs then when the app tries again immediately to communicate with the server, then the same error occurs. But after some time when the app tries to communicate, then there will be no problem of this. What is the error actually.? Can someone help me out. How to avoid this error??

This is the error log:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

Comment: Is your web service running on browser properly.Check it.

Comment: I have checked it. And my web service is correctly running on browser..

Comment: can you post ur code?

Comment: Please check [this][1] link and there is also many questions in SO.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703671/timeout-period-elapsed-all-pooled-connections-were-in-use-and-max-pool-size-rea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is time out exception u can check or increase time period like this

```
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("your SOAP_ADDRESS",60*10000);
```

Comment: What is the default timeout period in ksoap2?? Thanks for the answer. Let me check it.

Comment: dude actually i RND on this but i m didnt get default timeout period  for this but i just follow this and my prob solved so just try wd this once :)